# telegram sendAudio method not working

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm trying to use telegram sendAudio method as below :

`https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendAudio?chat_id=<chat_id>&audio=http://yon.ir/Qev1`

First I tried the actual link of my song ( http://dl.ir-song.net/Music/Eddie%20Attar%20-%20Rooberah.mp3 ) and the response was :

`{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Wrong HTTP URL specified"}`

So I shortened my url to http://yon.ir/Qev1 and now the response is :

`{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Failed to get HTTP URL content"}`

I tried some other songs from my host and again it didn't work , but when I try to send music from URLs of some other hosts and websites , in some cases it works. So what do you think ? The problem is from my host ? If so , what can I do ?

I appericiate any solutions from you , Thanks .

**Edit :**

1 > I used Google URL Shortener too and again it's not working .

2 > rjmediamusic.com/media/mp3/mp3-256/Moein-Rahbar-Ghose-Nakhor.mp3 this is a link that is working properly without shortening . ( form RadioJavan.com site )

Comment: did you solve this problem? I've the same problem now

Comment: Size of the file is very important. Reduce the size (less than 20MB) and test your bot. Check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/42860915/3768871