# Why i get Wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified error in telegram bot?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I'm new in telegram bot and try to send photo to user with this code:

```
await Bot.SendPhotoAsync(update.Message.Chat.Id, "http://182.126.201.42/" + "iisstart" + ".png");
```

but when i try run that code,get this error:

```
Bad Request: Wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified
```

How can i solve that problem?thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your URL is valid/can be accessed by telegram from the web? I cant access it myself

Comment: yes i can access,http://185.126.201.42/iisstart.png i mistake the up address

Comment: So the url you're using in your code that gives you that error message, is actually http://185.126.201.42/iisstart.png?

Comment: @JemarJones this https://codeshare.io/5X84p8 my code

Comment: @JemarJones what happen?

Comment: Not sure, that was just my first intuition

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be originated from the following issues:

- the image file extension is not allowed by the telegram.
- file size is larger than that allowed by the telegram.

You can start with the former one.

Answer (score 0):

Accoding to [example](https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot.examples/blob/master/Telegram.Bot.Examples.Echo/Program.cs) you can sendPhoto:

```
await Bot.SendChatActionAsync(message.Chat.Id, ChatAction.UploadPhoto);

            const string file = @"<FilePath>";

            var fileName = file.Split('\\').Last();

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                var fts = new FileToSend(fileName, fileStream);

                await Bot.SendPhotoAsync(message.Chat.Id, fts, "Nice Picture");
            }
```

Documentation: https://mrroundrobin.github.io/telegram.bot/html/M_Telegram_Bot_TelegramBotClient_SendPhotoAsync_3.htm