# Telegram Bot - Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified

Tags: python, web, telegram-bot

I have a weird problem with uploading a file to telegram via the `sendDocument` method. I am writing a bot in python with [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot). I try to send a ZIP file to a user, giving a URL as `document`.
This is the URL: http://telegram.someurl.tdl/32487352.zip

```python
bot.send_document(
    chat_id,
    document=document,
    filename=filename,
    timeout=60)
```

As much as I know my file follows the rules given by Telegram: http://telegram.someurl.tdl/32487352.zip

- Provide Telegram with an HTTP URL

  - `http://telegram.someurl.tdl/32487352.zip`
- 20 MB max

  - `2.14 MB`
- correct MIME type

  - `application/zip`
- sending by URL will currently only work for gif, pdf and zip files

  - `ZIP file`

These are the headers:

```
Accept-Ranges →bytes
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →2247049
Content-Type →application/zip
Date →Sun, 29 Oct 2017 21:15:36 GMT
ETag →"59f5e6e6-224989"
Last-Modified →Sun, 29 Oct 2017 14:34:14 GMT
Server →nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
```

The file is served by nginx (v1.10.3), with this simple configuration.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name telegram.someurl.tdl;

    root /path/to/download_dir;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Where `/path/to/download_dir` is replaced with the actual path of course.

The error I get, as said in the title, is this one:

```json
{
    "ok": false,
    "error_code": 400,
    "description": "Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified"
}
```

Also sending another ZIP file which I found online works: http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.zip

I already searched for a solution and eg. this [Telegram bot weird error : Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42697723/telegram-bot-weird-error-bad-request-wrong-file-identifier-http-url-specified) and this [Why i get Wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified error in telegram bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42048991/why-i-get-wrong-file-identifier-http-url-specified-error-in-telegram-bot) do not help.

I hope you guys can help me with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A friend of mine helped me and we could fix the problem. Everything I did was correct according to the Telegram Bot API documentation, but as it looks the documentation is not complete.

The problem was the name of my file. **The file must start with a letter**. It cannot start with a number. So eg. `test123.zip` and `t123.zip` work but `123.zip` or `1test.zip` do not.

**Update July 2020:**

It seems that Telegram has changed it's filename policy. I just tried with the following names and every single one worked. My guess is they accept any filename now though not every client saves the file the same way:

```
\-\-\-\-.zip   # in Telegram Desktop on Windows shown as "\-\-\-\-.zip" but saved as "_-_-_-_-.zip"
               # in Telegram on Android shown and saved as "----.zip"
hällo.zip
1.zip
test\nme.zip   # even with a filename with a literal new line character
               # in Telegram Desktop on Windows shown as "testme.zip" but saved as "test_me.zip"
               # in Telegram on Android shown and saved as "testme.zip"
tttt.zip
!test.zip
test!.zip
ttt.zip
t.zip
t1.zip
1t.zip
000.zip
äääää.zip
```

tested as follows:

```
for path in paths:
    print(path)
    chat.send_document('http://test.someurl.tdl/%s' % path, path)
```

Comment: I've had another problem, I was sending URL with port. Without port it worked. Even when file starts with a digit.

Answer (score 1):

The filename must be **at least 4 letters/digits long!** (t12.zip wouldn't work)

Answer (score 0):

Also, the file-name must be in English.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26556786)

Comment: I just added valuable missed info to the previous answer. Note, the author and me reveal undocumented tricks.